# OSCLASS region based listing like category page

Tags: url-rewriting, osclass

Using Osclass open source for listing website.

I want to listing like category page for region

See http://99business.co.uk/hotels.html

Its listing based on category. Display all listing within this category.

I want to display listing within region like

http://99business.co.uk/wiltshire-r742134

always give me error page instead of listing page for region.

So I want a page where I can display all listing which is in url.

Not sure may be its rewrite rule issue.

Its working when disabled rewrite rule.
http://99business.co.uk/index.php?page=search&sRegion=Wiltshire

Answer (score 0):

If it's working without permalinks, you should check permalinks rules in your admin panel under Settings > Permalinks, then 'Show rules'.

Having default configuration here's some examples of URLs:

- `http://osclass.dev/for-sale/`
- `http://osclass.dev/search/region,Texas`
- `http://osclass.dev/search/city,Dallas`
- `http://osclass.dev/search/region,Texas/city,Dallas`
- `http://osclass.dev/search/category,for-sale/region,Texas/city,Dallas`

Most of it is customizable.

Comment: Fixed, its overwrite ad listing url to region so I changed ad listing url. Now both are working.